# How does this inequality help me evaluate the limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose $b>0$. Compute 
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\left(\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^b-1\right). 
$$
My professor said that $e^{\frac{1}{n+1}} \leq 1 + 1/n$ can be used to evaluate the limit, but I do not see how this is done.

Now $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n((e^{\frac{1}{n+1}})^b-1) \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n((\frac{n+1}{n})^b-1)$, but I believe $n((e^{\frac{1}{n+1}})^b-1)$ converges, (Right?).

A hint as to how one should proceed would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "$n((e^{\frac1{n+1}})^b-1)$ converges, (Right?)":  Yes.  In fact, $n(x^{1/n}-1)\to\ln x$, so $n((e^{\frac1{n+1}})^b-1) = \frac{n}{n+1}\cdot(n+1)((e^b)^{1/(n+1)}-1)\to b$.

Comment: @StevenTaschuk Thank you. How might one show that $n(x^{1/n}-1) \rightarrow ln(x)$?

Comment: One might take it as the definition of $\ln$, but that's pretty rare.  Alternatively, $\lim_{n\to\infty} n(x^{1/n}-1) = \lim_{a\to 0^+} (x^a-1)/a = \left.\frac{d}{du} x^u\right|_{u=0} = \ln x$.

Comment: A looser intuitive argument is to note that $x\mapsto n(x^{1/n}-1)$ is the inverse function of $x\mapsto(1+\frac xn)^n$, so we expect that they converge to inverse functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that $e^{\frac{1}{n+1}} \leq 1 + \frac1n \leq e^\frac1n$. Then you can use the squeeze theorem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know approximations? because one can treat this question using:

$(1+\frac{1}{n})^b = 1 + \frac{b}{n} + o(\frac{1}{n})$

This gives you : $ n*[(1+\frac{1}{n})^b -1] =  b + o(1) \rightarrow b $ directly

As for your inequality,, I'm just not sure that it's the best approach. At least combine it with:

$\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2} \leq ln(1+\frac{1}{n}) \leq \frac{1}{n} $.

You can get your limit this way I think, if you note that: $ (\frac{n+1}{n})^b = e^{b*ln(1+\frac{1}{n})} $

Answer (score 0):

In other way, if $k=\lceil b\rceil$ then $b\leq k$, then

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\left[\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^b-1\right]\leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\left[\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^k-1\right]$$
How

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\left[\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^k-1\right]=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\left[\frac{n^k+\binom{k}{1}n^{k-1}+\cdots+1}{n^k}-1\right]=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\left[\frac{n^k+kn^{k-1}+\cdots+1-n^k}{n^k}\right]=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left[\frac{kn^{k}+\cdots+n}{n^k}\right]=k$$

then:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\left[\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^b-1\right]$$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

By L'Hopital, we have:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{(1+x)^b-1}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}b(1+x)^{b-1}=b.$$
Take $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$, and you get:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\left[(\frac{n+1}{n})^b-1\right]=b.$$